# Flip/page curl in android view

Tags: android, android-animation, flip

I have like a 10 images in my assets folder and i want to be able to give page curl animation when a button is pressed. Is there an animation that lets me do this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out ,

https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl

this is for sure will help u....

All the Best